# Why CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS does not accept json_encode?

Tags: php, json, curl, couchdb

`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` does not accept json_encode, but if I directly write the json in the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` if it is entered

This returns an error

> {"error":"bad_request","reason":"Request body must be a JSON object"}

```
    $bd = "fiscont_db_catalogo_cuentas";
    $ch = curl_init();

    $document ='{"docs":[{"key":"baz","name":"bazzel"},{"key":"bar","name":"barry"}]}';

    $json = json_encode($document);

    echo $json;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/'.$bd.'/_bulk_docs');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST'); /* or PUT */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-type: application/json',
        'Accept: */*'
    ));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'root:addc1243c');

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    echo $response;

    curl_close($ch);
```

but this is returning :

> [{"ok":true,"id":"8b3c672ffd4b8dcd7da313e9e9011243","rev":"1-f5f3f3e496c72307975a69c73fd53d42"},{"ok":true,"id":"8b3c672ffd4b8dcd7da313e9e9011c5a","rev":"1-8ad0e70d5e6edd474ec190eac2376bde"}]

```
    $bd = "fiscont_db_catalogo_cuentas";
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/'.$bd.'/_bulk_docs');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST'); /* or PUT */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"docs\":[{\"key\":\"baz\",\"name\":\"bazzel\"},{\"key\":\"bar\",\"name\":\"barry\"}]}");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-type: application/json',
        'Accept: */*'
    ));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'root:addc1243c');

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    echo $response;

    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_encode` takes an array or an object as a parameter. In your example, you encode a JSON string to JSON which doesn't make sens.

If you replace your line by this:

```
$document =['docs' => [['key'=>'baz','name'=>'bazzel'],['key'=>'bar','name'=>'barry']];
```

It will correctly convert your PHP associative array to JSON.